# Python: sorting tuple by last name and handling lower cased first letters

Tags: python

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> l = [(1.23, 'Smith'), (2.34, 'Jones'), (3.45, 'de la Smith')]
>>> ol = sorted(l, key=itemgetter(1))
>>> ol
[(2.34, 'Jones'), (1.23, 'Smith'), (3.45, 'de la Smith')]
```

How do I get the below list without some kludge using multiple list comprehensions?

```
[(3.45, 'de la Smith'), (2.34, 'Jones'), (1.23, 'Smith')]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can provide any function as the key. `itemgetter` is only useful for very simple cases

```
>>> L = [(1.23, 'Smith'), (2.34, 'Jones'), (3.45, 'de la Smith')]
>>> sorted(L, key=lambda x:x[1].lower())
[(3.45, 'de la Smith'), (2.34, 'Jones'), (1.23, 'Smith')]
```

for more complicated sorts, you may wish to write the function in the usual way

```
def item_to_sort_key(item):
    n, name = item
    return name.lower()

sorted(L, key=item_to_sort_key)
```

One advantage of writing it out the long way is that it's easier to write testcases for unusual names. It will also be handy if you ever have to start dealing with special cases.

If your Python is new enough you will have [`str.casefold`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) which should be used instead of `str.lower` because it handles unicode properly

Comment: I have started to use lambda's recently. I still don't understanding what lambda does in this particular use case. How does it work here?

Comment: @Cole, `lambda` is just a shorthand way of writing a function. Since it is usually inline, you don't need to give the function a name ans since it can only be a single expression, you don't need to explicitly say `return` as it will always return the result of the expression.

Comment: +1. Especially for mentioning `casefold`. (Not that you _can't_ do the equivalent with `locale` functions, `str` methods, and `unicodedata` functions in 3.2 and earlier… but it was so painful that you'd only do it if you were sure you needed it, while in 3.3, it's so simple that you can and should do it unless you're sure you _don't_ need it…)

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> l = [(1.23, 'Smith'), (2.34, 'Jones'), (3.45, 'de la Smith')]
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda tup: tup[1].lower())
[(3.45, 'de la Smith'), (2.33, 'Jones'), (1.23, 'Smith')]
```